# relation between discriminant and norm of ideals in Dedekind rings

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Consider a ring extension $R^{\prime}/R$ while their quotient fields form a finite separable extension. The relation between discriminant and norm of ideals are connected by $\Delta(I/R) = N(I)^2 \Delta(R^{\prime}/R)$. (which also holds true for fractional ideals) [Proposition 13, Chapter-3.3, Page 66 Lang, Algebraic Number Theory]

While proving this, it is useful to localise at non-zero maximal ideals and show the equality using the facts of discrete valuation rings.

However to make sure this machinery works one need to show one of these ideals are contained in another. Using the facts of basic properties of norm and discriminant I could compute : $\Delta(I/R) \supseteq N(a)^2 \Delta(R^{\prime}/R)$ for each $a \in I$. But this is not enough as $N(I)^2$ is generated over $R$ by elements like $N(a)N(b)$ while $a,b \in I$. Any help?

Does this goes through while we look at a non-separable extension as well?

Comment: When an extension of fields is not separable the trace map is identically 0, so what kind of statement were you expecting to show in that case other than $0 = 0$?

Comment: Thanks for this. Any comments about the first part? Am I missing something trivial?